# Spring AOP @annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm newbie in AOP especially in Spring AOP.

I want to log execution time in some specific method. I read Spring documentation
and considered that the best solution is to create aspect with annotation pointcut.

It looks like:

```
@Around("@annotation(com.x.y.MethodExecutionTime)")
public Object methodExecutionTimeLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

    Object retVal = null;
    try {
        stopWatch.start();
        retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        stopWatch.stop();
        logger.info("Execution time: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " ms");
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Execution time: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " ms");
        throw e;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Annotation is used in method:

```
    @Override
@MethodExecutionTime
public <T> T copy(Class<T> destType) {

    T t = ReflectionHelper.newInstance(destType);

    copyTo(t);

    return t;
}
```

Spring XML configuration:

```
<context:spring-configured />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

but it logs nothing.

I'm using Spring 3.0.5

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that uses this annotation?  Can you post the spring confiruation that does the setup for using Spring AOP?

Comment: Did you enable aop in spring xml? Show part of your xml spring configuration related to aop.

Comment: I posted it, is it necessary to add some other options to Spring xml configuration file?

Comment: Is the class that has the `@Around` method annotated with `@Aspect`?  Is it a part of the Spring application context?

Comment: Yes, it has @Aspect annotation and it is part of Spring Application context

Comment: What is retention type of `MethodExecutionTime` annotaion? Is it runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything else is configured properly, it should be one of the limitations of Spring AOP (at least, of its default configuration), namely:

- Object to apply the aspect to should be managed by Spring (i.e. it should be obtained from the application context, not created with `new`)
- Call should originate from the "outside" of that object, i.e. aspects are not applied when you call another method of the same object
- `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` should be declared in the same application context as the object to apply the aspect to (in particular, in a typical Spring Web MVC application `applicationContext.xml` and `...-servlet.xml` form different application contexts)

Comment: Hi axtavt, can you please check my post on Spring AOP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984258/basic-aop-program-throws-beancurrentlyincreationexception