# AOP applied to all public methods gives BeanCreationException exception

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have created a simple aspect that is applicable to all public methods like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicOperation() {
    }

    @Before("anyPublicOperation()")
    private void beforePointCut(){
        System.out.println("Inside before pointcut of MyAspect");
    }
}
```

I have below Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
//Enable AspectJ auto proxying
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.examples"})
public class Config {

    //Declare a bean
    @Bean
    public MyAspect myAspectProgram() {
        return new MyAspect();
    }
}
```

I am getting below exception when I load my configuration using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` class:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAspectProgram': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

If I change the pointcut expression then I don't get any exceptions, program is working fine.

Why I am getting issue when I have the pointcut expression as `@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")`?

Comment: you have asked [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31984258/1910582) some time back. Any particular reason you re-post it ? (*ideally original post should either be edited or deleted altogether*)

Comment: The other question is about more on with and without `@Component` annotation

Comment: I don't know the exact root cause of this but if you use any aspectj editor i.e. spring tool suite it shows compilation error saying the advice before needs to be public. I tried your code with public `@Before` advice method and it works.

Comment: @Setu, just now I tried by changing methods to public in aspect class, but getting same exception.

Comment: sorry can't help you anymore. That change seems to works for me. May be you want to clean build your workspace